# Как сделать копию базы?

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql

Добрый день!
Дано:
Linux - сервер с postgresql 9.4.

HDD 350 GB

БД work на этом сервере. Занимает 100 GB.

Мне нужно сделать на этом же сервере ещё две копии базы (work2 и work3).
Методом pg_dump мне не хватает места.

Как скопировать базу?

p.s. мне не нужна резервная копия. Мне нужна копия с которой я буду работать далее. Копии в дальнейшем будут изменяться. Компрессия не помогает - по факту гигов 20-30 останется на сервере, если три копии сделать. Не влезает.

Comment: А, то есть, вы хотите на одном сервере уместить 3 одинаковых базы? Так если база весит 100 Гб, у вас всё равно останется не больше 50 Гб, 20-30 это нормально. А вам зачем, кстати? Может, вашу задачу проще можно сделать.

Comment: Да, всё верно. Три базы. Мне нужно в эти базы внести разные изменения (Из одной базы одно удалить, из другой другое) и запустить хитрую обработку. То что не больше 50 гб - это нормально. Проблема в том, что представим: 100 гб база. 100Гб дамп. 100 Гб вторая база. Итого занято 300. А нужно загрузить в postgres ещё 100 гиг.

Comment: Сделайте бекап на другой сервер, копьютер, переносной фиск и  с него восстановите в две другие базы

Comment: Это виртуалка, в облаке, с грустным каналом. Задача была сделать всё _без_ добавления места.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашёл способ. Нужно было внимательнее читать [документацию](http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/backup-dump.html).

Запуск от пользователя postgres:

```
$ pg_dump -h localhost work | psql -h localhost work2
```

Comment: http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/backup-dump.html  Пункт 24.1.1 - таким образом можно и на другой хост потоком передать базу.

Answer (score 2):

Можно провернуть "создание из [шаблона](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html)", если к исходной базе никто не подключен (нет пишущих транзакций):

```
createdb -T старая новая
```

Подробности в `man createdb`.

Comment: Но данные-то не скопирует в новую базу?

Comment: @Sergey чего это вдруг? Полная копия **всей базы**, всех объектов, в том числе строк. Затем же и ограничение, чтобы данных никто не писал на тот момент.

Comment: В руководстве ничего не говорится о том, что template == структура + данные. Просто teplate какой-то и всё.

Comment: @Sergey строки тоже объекты. И они тоже копируются. Проверьте сами, если не верите :)